# How to weekly group if I have daily data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

i have following my table structure and data

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pairs_Details](
   [sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [userid] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [date] [datetime] NULL,
   [ljoin] [int] NULL,
   [rjoin] [int] NULL
       ) ON [PRIMARY]

sno userid          date                             ljoin  rjoin

1   LDS         2014-02-17 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
2   LDS         2014-02-17 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
3   LDS1        2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
4   LDS         2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
5   LDS1        2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              NULL   1
6   LDS         2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
7   SUNIL1      2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
8   LDS1        2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
9   LDS         2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
10  SUNIL1      2014-02-19 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
11  LDS1       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               1      NULL
12  LDS         2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1      NULL
13  SUNIL2     2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               1  NULL
14  LDS1          2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               NULL    1
15  LDS       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000                1      NULL
16  rajesh123  2014-02-19 00:00:00.000                   1  NULL
17  SUNIL1     2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
18  LDS1       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               1        NULL
19  LDS      2014-02-19 00:00:00.000                  1       NULL
20  SUNIL2     2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
21  LDS1       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
22  LDS        2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1          NULL
23  LDS2       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1         NULL
24  LDS        2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
25  SUNIL1     2014-02-20 00:00:00.000                  NULL        1
26  LDS1       2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              1        NULL
27  LDS    2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              1         NULL
28  rajesh123  2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              NULL     1
29  SUNIL1     2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
30  LDS1       2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              1         NULL
31  LDS     2014-02-20 00:00:00.000             1   NULL
32  LDS    2014-02-24 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
33  Jitendra123 2014-02-27 00:00:00.000             1   NULL
34  LDS2            2014-02-27 00:00:00.000             1   NULL
35  LDS         2014-02-27 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
36  rajeev123   2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
37  Jitendra123 2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
40  jyoti123    2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
41  SUNIL1          2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
42  LDS1            2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
43  LDS         2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
44  meeta           2014-03-01 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
45  jyoti123    2014-03-01 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
46  SUNIL1   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000                 1  NULL
47  LDS1     2014-03-01 00:00:00.000                      1 NULL
48  LDS  2014-03-01 00:00:00.000              1 NULL
38  LDS2     2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1 NULL
39  LDS  2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              NULL  1
```

**and this is my stored procdure .**

```
create proc [dbo].[pair_Scounting]
(
@userid nvarchar(50),
@start_date datetime,
@end_date datetime
)
as
begin
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT  userid,
Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) AS ljoin,
Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) AS rjoin, DATEPART(wk, Date) AS WeekNumber,
CASE 
WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date]))) < YEAR(Min([date]))
THEN CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, 0 ,GETDATE())), 0) AS Varchar(50))   + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
ELSE
Cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date])) AS Varchar(50)) + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
END  DateRange,
Case 
 When Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) < Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) Then Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) 
  When Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) < Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) Then Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) 
  Else (Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0))-1) 
End  pair
FROM Pairs_Details  where  userid=@userid and date between @start_date and @end_date
Group By userid,DATEPART(wk, Date)
end
GO
```

if i execute my stored procedure as follows it return following result

```
exec pair_Scounting 'LDS','2014-02-17','2014-02-28'



userid  ljoin   rjoin   WeekNumber  DateRange                               pair

 LDS    10        2       8     Feb 17 2014 12:00AM TO Feb 23 2014 12:00AM    2
 LDS    1         3       9     Feb 24 2014 12:00AM TO Mar  2 2014 12:00AM    1
```

but i want if i execute my stored procedure it return my desired result as follows

please read carefully above my stored procedure  which is used to count pair weekly

my desired output following

```
userid  ljoin   rjoin   WeekNumber  DateRange                               pair

 LDS    10        2       8     Feb 17 2014 12:00AM TO Feb 23 2014 12:00AM    2
 LDS    9         3       9     Feb 24 2014 12:00AM TO Mar  2 2014 12:00AM    3
```

if (ljoin>rjoin) then ljoin-rjoin(10-2=8) value must be added to ljoin of next week and

so ljoin of next week from Feb 24 2014 12:00AM TO Mar  2 2014 12:00AM is 8+1=9 according my data

if (rjoin>ljoin) then rjoin-ljoin value must be added to rjoin of next week

so how it can be done please any can suggest us.

thanks

Comment: your question needs better readability and clarification, especially regarding "following calculation"

Comment: what is the SQL Version you are on?